# App Specific Google Account

Tags: android, google-api, accountmanager, google-account

I am looking at utilizing a Google api for some functionality in an Android app and as such, users will require a Google account. I will need to create a new account within the app as other users should not be aware of the user's info for privacy reasons, so using an existing account is probably not advisable. Wondering if it's possible to hide newly generated accounts  from the AccountManager so the user cannot mistakenly start using the account created in the app for sending emails or any other tasks from this account. Also wondering if it's possible to run a session in a browser specific to one Google account while keeping other accounts logged in in other sessions. Sorry if this is a totally unrealistic question.

Answer (score 0):

In chrome go to the **settings** and you will see something called **users**.

In here you can have multiple profiles which is what you are after and they have a different icon next to them so that you can tell which account you are in.  I find this useful not only for what you are trying to do but for if I want to test something related to cookies/cache etc where I can go to the site as a different account.

Comment: Thanks for the response ak85. I am actually looking to see if I can hide an account from the area you are referring to as I don't want a user to be using the google account created in the app for any other tasks such as email, google+ etc as I would like the user to remain somewhat annonymous when using google api functionality while in the app. If they were to mistakenly use the account, go to google+ and say use their name in a post, they would no longer be using the app anonymously.

Comment: Ok if you go to google.com/settings there is something about deleting your g+ account might be worrh reading this link to see if you can still mansge apps etc https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1044503?hl=en